# simple sql over (partition by) not working as expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions

Feels like it should be simple but my mind has gone blank so would appreciate any help!

Let's say I have this dataset

```
Date     sale_id    salesperson Missed_payment_this_month
01/01/2016  1001    John         1
01/01/2016  1002    Bob          0
01/01/2016  1003    Bob          0
01/01/2016  1004    John        N/A
01/02/2016  1001    John         1
01/02/2016  1002    Bob          1
01/02/2016  1003    Bob          0
01/02/2016  1004    John         1
01/03/2016  1001    John         1
01/03/2016  1002    Bob          0
01/03/2016  1003    Bob          0
01/03/2016  1004    John         1
```

And want to add these two columns to the end. They look at the number of missed payments previously, by sales_id and salesperson.

```
Previous_missed_payment_by_sale_id  Previous_missed_payment_by_sales person
    0                                           0
    0                                           0
    0                                           0
    0                                           0
    1                                           1
    0                                           0
    0                                           0
    0                                           1
    2                                           3
    1                                           1
    0                                           1
    1                                           3
```

sales_id is ok but getting it over sales persons is giving me an error (group by) or adding in extra columns. I need to keep the rows constant.

My best guess that returns extra columns:

```
 select t1.Date, t1.sale_id, t1.salesperson
 ,sum(case when t2.Missed_payment_this_month = '1' then 1 else 0 end)             previous_missed_sales_id
 ,sum(case when t2.Missed_payment_this_month = '1' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION by t1.salesperson) previous_missed_salesperson

 from [dbo].[simple_join_table2] t1
 inner join [dbo].[simple_join_table2] t2 on 
(t2.[Date] < t1.[Date] AND t1.[sale_id] = t2.[sale_id])

 group by t1.Date, t1.sale_id, t1.salesperson
 ,case when t2.Missed_payment_this_month = '1' then 1 else 0 end
```

this is the output:

```
Date    sale_id salesperson previous_missed_sales_id    previous_missed_salesperson
01/02/2016  1002    Bob         0                                   1
01/02/2016  1003    Bob         0                                   1
01/03/2016  1002    Bob         0                                   1
01/03/2016  1002    Bob         1                                   1
01/03/2016  1003    Bob         0                                   1
01/02/2016  1001    John        1                                   3
01/02/2016  1004    John        0                                   3
01/03/2016  1001    John        2                                   3
01/03/2016  1004    John        0                                   3
01/03/2016  1004    John        1                                   3
```

Is this possible without another sub query? I guess another way to put it is i'm trying to mimic the sumx and earlier functions of Powerpivot.

Comment: If you included your expected output, that would be a big help.

Comment: Good point, I have attached that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on 2012+ use windowing aggregates. Previous = sum all_previous_including_curret - sum current. Ms sql default window is exactly `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

```
with [simple_join_table2] as(
    -- sample data
    select cast(valuesDate as Date) valuesDate, sale_id, salesperson, Missed_payment_this_month 
    from (
        values
         ('20160101',1001,'John', 1)
        ,('20160101',1002,'Bob ', 0)
        ,('20160101',1003,'Bob ', 0)
        ,('20160101',1004,'John',null)
        ,('20160201',1001,'John', 1)
        ,('20160201',1002,'Bob ', 1)
        ,('20160201',1003,'Bob ', 0)
        ,('20160201',1004,'John', 1)
        ,('20160301',1001,'John', 1)
        ,('20160301',1002,'Bob ', 0)
        ,('20160301',1003,'Bob ', 0)
        ,('20160301',1004,'John', 1)
    ) t(valuesDate, sale_id, salesperson, Missed_payment_this_month)
)
select valuesDate,sale_id, salesperson, Missed_payment_this_month, 
  byidprevmonth = sum(Missed_payment_this_month ) over(partition by sale_id order by valuesDate)
        - sum(Missed_payment_this_month) over(partition by valuesDate, sale_id),
  bypersonprevmonth = sum(Missed_payment_this_month) over(partition by salesperson order by valuesDate) 
        - sum(Missed_payment_this_month) over(partition by valuesDate, salesperson)
from [simple_join_table2] 
order by salesperson, valuesDate
```